# React Google Maps InfoWindow Offset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using the [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) library.  I have markers on my map with an info window that loads all fine but I need to reposition the infowindow just a tad so it's rendering above the marker and not right on top of it thereby hiding it. I know there is a way to do it with `InfoWindowOptions` but I'm not quite sure on the syntax to get it working. Here's my `Map.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const Map = () => {
  const defaultCenter = {
    center: {
      lat: 41.51,
      lng: -75.22
    },
  }
  const defaultZoom = {
    zoom: 10
  };
  const [showingInfoWindow, setShowingInfoWindow] = useState(false);
  const [selectedPlace, setSelectedPlace] = useState();

  const onMarkerClick = (marker, place) => {
    setShowingInfoWindow(true);
    setSelectedPlace(place);
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    if (showingInfoWindow) {
      setShowingInfoWindow(false);
      setSelectedPlace(null);
    }
  };

  const containerStyle = {
    width: '500px',
    height: '500px'
  };

  const places = // API call to get places

  return (
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey={ /* key */ }
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={defaultCenter.center}
        zoom={defaultZoom.zoom}
      >
        { selectedPlace && <InfoWindow
          position={selectedPlace.location}
          options={{ pixelOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 } }}
          visible={showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={onClose}
        >
          <div>test</div>
        </InfoWindow>}
        {places.map((place) => (
          <>
            <Marker
              key={loc.key}
              onClick={(props) => onMarkerClick(props, loc)}
              position={place.location}
            />
          </>
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

I'd like to pass in an `InfoWindowOptions` object through the `options` field of `InfoWindow` like so:

```
<InfoWindow
          options={{ pixelOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 } }}
/>
```

But this doesn't work. So I tried doing

```
const options = {
  pixelOffset: {
    Size: google.maps.Size(10, 10),
  }
}
```

But then I get the "google is not defined" error. I've tried using `useJsApiLoader` and setting `/* global google */` at the top of my file and nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out. You can add the options property to your `InfoWindow` like this:

`<InfoWindow options={{ pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(0, -40) }}></InfoWindow>`